# using google's data.join to interatively add data to a graph

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to build a set of data for a Google scatter graph using data.join as follows:

```
var tempData = newData();
var tempData2 = totalData;
dataArray[dataCount] = tempData;
var joinMark = countArray(dataCount);
totalData = google.visualization.data.join(tempData2,tempData,'full',[[0,0]],[joinMark],[1]);
dataCount = dataCount+1;
```

Where newData() generates a dataTable from a database, column 0 is always a date and column 1 is always a number. I have been able to get this to work once, to display 2 variables on the graph, but trying to add any more causes my code to fail.

BTW totalData is the variable passed to `chart.draw()`

The countArray function returns 1 if both arrays have 2 columns (works fine), but for further additions I am returning a comma separated string 1,2... 1,2,3.. etc. This is based on my assumption that that last two variables in data.join are the column numbers from dataTable 1 and 2 respectively to be combined. Am I right in this assumption, or do I need a different variable in that location?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct about the function of the last two parameters in the join call, but you do not want to pass a comma-separated string where `joinMark` is: that should be an array of column indices, not an array containing a string.  You cannot add a comma-separated string to an array to get an array on integers:

```
var joinMark = '1,2,3';
[joinMark] == [1,2,3]; // false
```

Change your `countArray` function to return an array of integers instead, and then pass that array directly to the join function (that is, you shouldn't wrap it in brackets to create an array of arrays):

```
var joinMark = countArray(dataCount);
totalData = google.visualization.data.join(tempData2,tempData,'full',[[0,0]],joinMark,[1]);
```